# "sort&compress" and "nocite" do not work for latex-pdf in rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

My **pure-latex** `demo.tex` is as follows:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbers,super,square,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}

statistics \cite{anderson2003introduction,efron2004least,hastie2009elements}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{ref}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}

\end{document}
```

and it works well, where `ref.bib` contains

```
@Book{anderson2003introduction,
  author    = {Anderson, Theodore Wilbur},
  publisher = {Wiley},
  title     = {An introduction to multivariate statistical analysis},
  year      = {2003},
  address   = {New Jersey},
  edition   = {3},
}
@Article{efron2004least,
  author    = {Efron, Bradley and Hastie, Trevor and Johnstone, Iain and Tibshirani, Robert},
  title     = {Least angle regression},
  journal   = {The Annals of Statistics},
  year      = {2004},
  volume    = {32},
  number    = {2},
  pages     = {407--499},
}
@Book{hastie2009elements,
  author    = {Hastie, Trevor and Tibshirani, Robert and Friedman, Jerome},
  publisher = {Springer},
  title     = {The elements of statistical learning: {Data} mining, inference, and prediction},
  year      = {2009},
  address   = {New York},
  edition   = {2},
}
@Book{fan2020statistical,
  author    = {Fan, Jianqing and Li, Runze and Zhang, Cun-Hui and Zou, Hui},
  publisher = {CRC},
  title     = {Statistical foundations of data science},
  year      = {2020},
  address   = {Boca Raton},
}
```

I want to translate `demo.tex` to the rmarkdown file `tex2rmd.rmd` and I try

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    citation_package: natbib
natbiboptions: "numbers,super,square,sort&compress"
# natbiboptions: "numbers,super,square" #test
biblio-style: unsrtnat
nocite: '@*'
bibliography: ref.bib
link-citations: yes
colorlinks: no
---

statistics [@anderson2003introduction; @efron2004least; @hastie2009elements]

# References
```

which gives errors like

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \&
l.351 \newcommand
                 \NAT@aysep{,} \newcommand\NAT@yrsep{,}
```

Then I check the `tex2rmd.tex` file from the `keep_tex: yes` functionality, and I find the problem happens at

```
\usepackage[numbers,super,square,sort\&compress]{natbib}
```

where there is `sort\&compress` instead of `sort&compress`. How can I fix this?

Moreover, I use `natbiboptions: "numbers,super,square"` instead for test purpose and find the `nocite: '@*'` does't work either (it should show all 4 items other than the cited 3 items). Do I ignore something?

Comment: I found this issue: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/781 , they solved it by using the sort and compress option individually ( \usepackage[numbers,super,square,sort, compress]{natbib} ). I have no experience with it, but maybe it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing the `&` from `sort&compress` with `,` solves the issue of `sort&compress`.

And it seems the `nocite` YAML key doesn't work when you use `natbib` or `biblatex` as the citation package. Because `nocite` key is used by `pandoc-citeproc` filter, but when `natbib` or `biblatex` is used as citation method (default is [`citeproc`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citation-rendering)), `pandoc-citeproc` is not used then and `nocite` doesn't work as well.

In that case, you need to use the raw LaTeX command `\nocite` ([as explained here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1253#issuecomment-98766257))

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    citation_package: natbib
natbiboptions: "numbers,super,square,sort,compress"
biblio-style: unsrtnat
bibliography: ref.bib
link-citations: yes
colorlinks: no
---

\nocite{*}

statistics [@anderson2003introduction; @efron2004least; @hastie2009elements]

# References
```

---

[image: bibliography]

---

Comment: Tks! it works well for the `sort&compress` issue! @shafee  Still no idea why `nocite: '@*'` doesn't work. Maybe manually add the latex command `\nocite{*}` directly after the `# References`......

Comment: Since I have all 4 items in the `ref.bib` and only have cited 3 items

Comment: Oh I have completely overlooked the issue of `nocite` happening here. :). Ok let me see what I can do.

Comment: Very clear and definite! @shafee

Comment: @JohnStone Added more info actually. :D

Answer (score 2):

To avoid all the problems with rmarkdown parsing and give you much more freedom, you can directly use the latex code in rmarkdown:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
link-citations: yes
colorlinks: no
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[numbers,super,square,sort&compress]{natbib}
---

\nocite{*}

statistics \cite{anderson2003introduction,efron2004least,hastie2009elements}

# References

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{ref}
```

Comment: Very impressive `nearly-latex` style solution and quite flexible and customizable !@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: @JohnStone From my ongoing series of "how to use rmarkdown without using rmarkdown" :)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz,  earnestly want to see that series as a book as it would increase my latex knowledge at an exponential rate (I am sure of it) :)

Comment: @shafee :) If you would like to to increase your latex knowledge: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/612586/36296 -- I'm eagerly waiting for it to be released.