# biblatex for the unsrt style with super-compact-numeric in square brackets in latex or rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

My problem arises from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75095113), with the help of `@shafee` and `@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz`, where the demo `.tex` and `.rmd` are also supplied therein.

My idea is that I want to use `biblatex` other than `natbib` to get the same goals. There are several obstacles, since the default `biblatex` doesn't hold for **the unsrt style  with super-compact-numeric in square brackets**. I try my best to solve them one by one.

## the unsrt style (bibstyle)

From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58152/ , we resort to `style=trad-unsrt` in `biblatex-trad`, i.e.

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=trad-unsrt]{biblatex}
```

## the compact numeric (citestyle)

From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61524, we resort to `citestyle=numeric-comp` in `biblatex`, i.e.

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=trad-unsrt,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
```

## the super style (citestyle; position-of-citation)

From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355111/, we resort to `autocite=superscript` in `biblatex`, i.e.

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=trad-unsrt,citestyle=numeric-comp,autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
```

## finally; current `.tex` and `.rmd` files

### tex

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=trad-unsrt,citestyle=numeric-comp,autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\newcommand{\citep}[1]{\autocite{#1}}

\begin{document}

statistics \citep{anderson2003introduction,efron2004least,hastie2009elements}

\printbibliography[heading=bibliography,title=References]
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

### rmd

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: ref.bib
biblatexoptions:
  - backend=biber
  - style=trad-unsrt
  - citestyle=numeric-comp
  - autocite=superscript
link-citations: yes
colorlinks: no
header-includes:
  - \newcommand{\citep}[1]{\autocite{#1}}
---

statistics [@anderson2003introduction; @efron2004least; @hastie2009elements]

\nocite{*}
```

### question?

Both `.tex` and `.rmd` can compile smoothly and it is nearly successful, while `the remaining one thing` is that **I don't know how to add `square brackets` to the `super-compact-numeric` citation**. Btw, I also search for similar issues such as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341041), where the `biblatex-ext` therein maybe helpful. However, I don't know how to make compatible between `biblatex-ext` and `biblatex-trad`. Any other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `chem-angew` style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew,autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\newcommand{\citep}[1]{\autocite{#1}}


\begin{document}

statistics \citep{anderson2003introduction,efron2004least,hastie2009elements}

\printbibliography[heading=bibliography,title=References]
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! A brief efficient solution except  that one must accept the default  `chem-angew` bib-style and can not use  other bib-styles such as `trad-unsrt`   or  `trad-abbrv`...@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: Wow, finally I solve the problem based on your work! Just use `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=trad-unsrt,citestyle=chem-angew,autocite=superscript]{biblatex}` @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  Or  use  `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibstyle=trad-unsrt,citestyle=chem-angew,autocite=superscript]{biblatex}`. Splendid!

Answer (score 3):

Normally you could redefine the `\mkbibsuperscript` macro to add the square brackets. Unfortunately rmarkdown for some inexplicable reasons delays loading the biblatex package until after the header includes, so one needs to hack a bit:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: ref.bib
biblatexoptions:
  - backend=biber
  - style=trad-unsrt
  - citestyle=numeric-comp
  - autocite=superscript
link-citations: yes
colorlinks: no
header-includes:
  - \newcommand{\citep}[1]{\autocite{#1}}
  - \makeatletter\AtEndPreamble{\renewrobustcmd{\mkbibsuperscript}[1]{\unspace\allowhyphens\textsuperscript{[\begingroup\protected\long\def\mkbibsuperscript##1{\blx@warning{Nested superscript}\mkbibbrackets{##1}}#1\endgroup]}}}\makeatother
---

statistics [@anderson2003introduction; @efron2004least; @hastie2009elements]

\nocite{*}
```

[image]

Comment: It works, but it's a little complicated for me (with limited latex knowledge)! @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: In my opinion, citations with `parentheses` or `brackets` are fundamental, as in  `\usepackage[numbers,super,square,sort&compress]{natbib}` with `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`. No idea why this happens for `biblatex` ...